# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, wildfly

I have upgraded spring version in my appliation from 4.3.18.RELEASE to 5.1.5.RELEASE and now getting deployment error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter
```

With Spring version - 4.3.18.RELEASE and app server wildfly-16.0.0.FINAL, deployment was successful but with spring veersion - 5.1.5.RELEASE, getting above error.

Can anyone give me any clue what other changes I have to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove this bean (class no more existing in 5.x) and add:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```